# Mediaelementjs 2.14.0 not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I am using Mediaelementjs 2.14.0 and it's working fine in modern browser. When i run it in IE8  and click to play then it ask me to download video file.

## html

```
<div class="player-container">
<video width="640" height="360" id="demo-player" poster="media/echo-hereweare.jpg" controls preload="none" autoplay>
    <!-- MP4 source must come first for iOS -->
    <source type="video/mp4" src="media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />
    <!-- WebM for Firefox 4 and Opera -->
    <source type="video/webm" src="media/echo-hereweare.webm" />
    <!-- OGG for Firefox 3 -->
    <source type="video/ogg" src="media/echo-hereweare.ogv" />

    <!-- Fallback flash player for no-HTML5 browsers with JavaScript turned off -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="js/flashmediaelement.swf">      
        <param name="movie" value="js/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />      
        <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
        <img src="media/echo-hereweare.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Here we are" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>   
</video>
</div>
```

## js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#demo-player').mediaelementplayer();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does Anything Works in `IE8` ?? :D

Comment: No. It shows just poster image.